# Using linkTo within a custom Handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using a Handlebars helper to parse a set of objects and I'd like the returned result to be wrapped in a #linkTo call so Embers router will pick it up.

Here's how I'm calling it in the view:
`{{buildBreadcrumb my_objects}}`

Here's what my helper looks like:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper 'buildBreadcrumb', (val, opts) ->
  value = Ember.get(this, val)
  out = ""
  value.forEach (group, index) =>
    if value.length - index == 2
      out += '{{#linkTo group ' + group.name + '}}'
    if value.length - index == 1
      out += '{{#linkTo group ' + group.name + '}}'
  out
```

The above just parses out the `{{#linkTo ...}}` as a literal string for obvious reasons.  Is there any way that I can get it parsed the way I'm looking to do it?  I'm well aware of the fact that I can use {{#each}}, etc... in the view itself - but because of my use-case I sort of have to use a helper to build this out.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom Handlebars view helper. That view could encapsulate the `#each` logic while the final helper would look mostly similar to what you have here. The only difference in use is having to pass in the arguments as attributes to the View helper.

The way to create this helper is to pass in the View class instead of the helper function.

```
App.BreadcrumbView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'breadcrumb',
  penultimate: function() {
    var length = this.get('items').length;
    return this.get('items')[length - 2];
  }.property('items'),
  last: function() {
    var length = this.get('items').length;
    return this.get('items')[length - 1];
  }.property('items')
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('breadcrumb', App.BreadcrumbView);
```

And the corresponding template,

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='breadcrumb'>
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    {{#each item in view.items}}
      <li>{{#linkTo 'group' item}}{{item.id}}{{/linkTo}} &raquo;
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>    
</script>
```

And to use the helper in the app,

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='breadcrumb'>
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li>{{#linkTo 'group' view.penultimate}}{{view.penultimate.id}}{{/linkTo}} &raquo;</li>
    <li>{{#linkTo 'group' view.last}}{{view.last.id}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
  </ul>    
</script>
```

A benefit with this approach is the bindings are automatically connected, so changing the items data would auto-update the breadcrumb view, preserving the internal Metamorphing.

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ucosik/4/) example.

Comment: I upvoted your answer thanks to the effort you put in - I appreciate it.  My biggest problem, however, is not iterating through the items and making them links (as you demonstrated I could do that with a simple #each call).  My problem is that I only want to show the last two items in the array and link to those - I don't want the full breadcrumb trail (if that makes sense).  That's why I'm checking the index of the items in the example code I gave above.  Any way to do that with the example you gave?

Comment: Sure, You could use computed properties that point to the items at the specific indices, and then use those properties in the template. See updated code.